# Can't use sculpting tool whatsoever (and it's not the vertices issue)

Tags: sculpt

Can't use sculpting tool to any effect whatsoever.
I checked the Shape keys ( I have nothing there), checked scale (1,1,1), have a multires Modifier on, have plenty of vertices.

What's the issue?
[image]

Comment: Try a subsurf modifier, maybe.

Comment: Is the mask active and prevents sculpting? (Blender 3.0.0 has a little update issue. The mask is not always visible. Switch the mask off & on in the overlay menu to refresh)

Comment: okay. when I apply the subdivide modifier, it works beautifully. But when I add a multires modifier, or apply it, it does nada. What's with that?

Answer (score 4):

Solved. It was a silly mistake of having a texture on that does nothing on Draw tool. Everything else works fine again for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for posting what solved your problem, even if it might seem "silly" or unusual. It might help someone else. And for the rest of us, we are not left wondering what it could have been. We can add "textures that do nothing" to the sculpting troubleshooting checklist. ;-)